# Не корректная работа Vusual Studio. Берет код из динамической копии

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

Привет народ.Кода нет но есть вопрос.Проблема в том что студия(17 версия) берет код javascript из динамической копии а не из самого файла со скриптами.
вот картинка что бы понятнее было.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
этот раздел появляется когда запущено приложение и скрипты студия берет оттуда. В самом файле у меня уже давно другой код я  и его 100 раз сохранял и даже студию перезапустил.Ранее все было ок сохранения применялись. Ранее я публиковал(на хостинг) проект может из за этого берет из  из ранее сохраненной версии  еще почему не пойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать нажать правой кнопкой в Обозревателе решений и выбрать пункт Очистить, после этого снова построить проект

Comment: А нет ок вроде ща перестали работать. Спасибо